# How to see in Apache logs request processing time, not request serving time

Tags: apache, process, request, logging

There is an Apache 2 server choking under multiple requests. Amount of processes reaches number set by Maxclient, and new connections pile up in queue. I need to identify which requests take too much time x amount of requests.
Apache logs may show either:

%...D   The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds.

or

%...T   The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.

And this time taken to *serve* the requests make it's hard to analyze. Because at the time when process table overflows is the time around which I need to measure. And there serve time equals *time spent in connection queue* plus *time processed*.

So a .php script which took 2 seconds will show 2 seconds. And .cgi script which spent minute (real data ;)) in queue will show 60.5 seconds.

Is there a way to log time taken to process requests, preferably not involving engaging with hooks?

Answer (score 1):

Probable this is what you were looking for:
https://code.google.com/p/mod-log-firstbyte/